# How to run code before ApplicationRunner in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am making a unit test of a few spring components, the major one being an `ApplicationRunner` that is run automatically by spring.

However, I have to run a piece of code before this `ApplicationRunner` bean is called.

=> How can I do that?

I tried to use `@Before` and `@PostConstruct` but both are called after the AppllicationRunner.

I cannot share the actual code but here is the principle:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// The class to be tested
// Comes with many bean, the main one being an ApplicationRunner
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApplication.class })
public class MyApplicationTest {

    @Autowired private SomeProperties someProperties;

    // the method I need to run before the ApplicationRunner    
    @PostConstruct // also tried @Before
    public void clean() throws IOException {
        // need to be sure some output dir is empty before starting
        cleanOutputDirectory(someProperties);
    }


    @Test
    public void testApplication() throws InterruptedException {
        // test the ApplicationRunner has written some files
        // in the output directory
    }
}
```

Comment: share us the snippet what have you tried

Comment: I added a prototype of what I am doing

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing the `ApplicationRunner` in isolation with a proper unit test so that you can actually control when it is invoked.

Comment: The ApplicationRunner is already tested in isolation. Here I want to test the whole app that is much more complex than simply the runner.

Comment: If you tested it in isolation then why test it again? Also the `@BeforeClass` should work, althoughyou cannot access properties or anything from the context like you can in an `@Before`. What you can do is use an `@TestPropertySource` to randomly generate a directory to write to, and use that for your test. Delete it after the test, that way you don't need to clean it as it will differ for each test run.

Comment: Sorry I made an error in the sample code. It is Before that I tried because I cannot use BeforeClass as I need the non static property (as you mentioned)

Comment: Your proposition to output to a randomly generated folder is interesting and actually better than what I do. But I am not sure if I can use it in my situation because the choice of the output folder is part of the tested functionality and is coupled to some input folder (which is provided for the test). I will look into it

Comment: Apparently  your test directory is configurable, judging from the `SomeProperties` that are injected. If you use an `@TestPropertySourec(properties = "your.path.property=#{some.random.value}"` then both your test will have the random test directory and your application. That way it should always be empty at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new `ApplicationRunner` bean in tests with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple **ApplicationRunner** beans can be defined within the same application context and can be ordered using the Ordered interface or @Order annotation. Use one for your testing.

Comment: source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html